# Generate PDF for all the sharepoint item details or part of the fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate

I want to implement this:-

1. MS Flow >> which get triggered when the item status = "Completed" >> and it will generate 2 PDF files >> save the files to SharePoint document library
2. The first PDF will contain all the item's fields , while the second PDF will contain some of the item's fields (this will be predefined).

now i found this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Da4do2DxmJE which implement generating PDF files, but it has the following limitation:-

1. the file size can only be 2 MB max.
2. the file need to be created inside OneDrive.

so how i can achieve the above without the limitations, so mainly allowing the PDF it be as large as needed (something between 10 MB-20 MB) + does not save anything to OneDrive?
Thanks